# HTML5 video tag not working on 000webhost

Tags: html, html5-video

My video work fine locally but when I put it on the server it doesn't work I have both file uploaded and are in the default directory.

```
  <html>
   <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video.css">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="banner" class="headerContent">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent" class="headerContent">
            <video autoplay   id="awsome_video" >
               <source src="promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="overlay">
           <h1 id="rowdy"> ROWDY RONDY ROUSEY </h1>
           <a href="test.html" id="enter">ENTER</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your video src path mismatching :

```html
  <html>
   <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video.css">
   </head>
   <body>
        <div id="banner" class="headerContent">
      <div id="header">
        <div id="headerContent" class="headerContent">
            <video autoplay   id="awsome_video" >
               <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        <div class="overlay">
           <h1 id="rowdy"> ROWDY RONDY ROUSEY </h1>
           <a href="test.html" id="enter">ENTER</a>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: <video autoplay   id="awsome_video" >
               <source src="http://derrylahan.comze.com/promo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

Comment: How is the link to the video obtained ?

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem but i put the file in my code and it worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
        <!-- Other elements -->
        <staticContent>
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4v" mimeType="video/m4v" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".oga" mimeType="audio/ogg" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>
          <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is web.config. Put this file where index file exists.

Comment: is theis a .xml file ?

Comment: still wont load even if i add controls the video just isnt loading to the webpage

Comment: index.html  promo.mp4 & web.config.xml are all in the same directory

Comment: Do u also have .htaccess file there?

Comment: I had used <figure class="video" data-mp4="video.mp4" data-ogv="video.ogv" data-webm="video.webm" ></figure>
instead of<video> tag

Comment: Still no look maybe its the hosting service im using 000Webhost free version?

Comment: what did you call the we.config file and does it have to be called in index.html

Comment: No, jut put it where u have index.html and the name is web.config. I think may be there is a issue because htaccess and web config, both are there

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 000Webhost is using some type of Unix-based hosting (ie, Apache), not ASP.NET. To the best of my memory, for Apache, MIME type configurations should go in httpd.conf. However, for my host, "BlueHost", they actually had an admin control panel on the web that was able to guide me through adding MIME types to my server - it was pretty straightforward, you're just associating file extensions like ".mp4" to "MIME" strings like "video/mp4". 000Webhost may have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently 000Webhost's free service does not support audio/video streaming and this is why it is not working